# MYSQL Select * distinct id where char != A

Tags: mysql, sql

```
|id|___|char|
|12|___|  A |
|57|___|  B |
|12|___|  C |
```

i wanted to select all distinct id values != A...

my query gives me 57 & 12 which is right...but i don't want `12 | C` since it has another pair related which is `12 | A`  ....

how can i select rows where if id '12' has any relation to A all other id '12' with different values will not be selected?

Comment: "my query give me ..."  So where's the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE char = 'A')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINT id 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE char = 'A')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,Char
FROM your_table
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE CHAR = 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINT id,Char FROM table WHERE char != 'A'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum( char = 'A' ) = 0;
```